# Create custom wpf event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, custom-event

i've created an UserControl for Database connection where user input Username and Password for a connection.
This UserControl is in a MainWindow.xaml

Now, in code behind of my UserControl i create a MSSQL connection. If login Successfully, i want to Raise a custom event to expose in MainWindow.

**For example in MyUserControl.xaml.cs**

```
try
{

    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connessione Riuscita!", "Connessione a " + TextIP.Text, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        RaiseMyEvent();
        sqlConn.Close();                 
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connessione Fallita: " + ex.Message, "Connessione a " + TextIP.Text, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

**and In MainWindow.xaml i want to use mypersonalized event:**

```
<Window x:Class="XLogin.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XLogin" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <local:DBLogin x:Name="DBLoginFrame" MyPersonalizedUCEvent="DBLoginFrame_MyPersonalizedUCEvent"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I need this for multiple type connection (MSSQL, Oracle, MySql etc).

How to get this?

Answer (score 28):

First you should define a delegate and then use that delegate to define that event.

In your MyUserControl.xaml.cs file add the following

Option 1

```
    public delegate void MyPersonalizedUCEventHandler(string sampleParam);

    public event MyPersonalizedUCEventHandler MyPersonalizedUCEvent;

    public void RaiseMyEvent()
    {
        // Your logic
        if (MyPersonalizedUCEvent != null)
        {
            MyPersonalizedUCEvent("sample parameter");
        }
    }
```

And that's it. You have defined your event.

Option 2

```
    public event Action<String> MyPersonalizedUCEvent;

    public void RaiseMyEvent()
    {
        // Your logic
        if (MyPersonalizedUCEvent != null)
        {
            MyPersonalizedUCEvent("sample parameter");
        }
    }
```

More about the `Action` delegate can be found in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Note:**

In many cases if events are not used properly they can cause memory leaks. Just make sure that you have written code to remove the registered event handlers as shown below.

```
        MyPersonalizedUCEvent -= MyPersonalizedUCEventHandler;
```

Comment: @davymartu But instead of defining your own delegate type, you would usually use one of the pre-defined ones, like [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) or [EventHandler<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx).

Comment: I have defined a simple event. However, if you want the event to bubble to the parent container you should create a Routed Event and iltzortz answer explains how to create it.

Comment: First option was suitable for my case.

Answer (score 16):

First create a public event in your class :

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomethingChanged;
```

**NB** `MyEventArgs` is the type of object that will be passed with the event to subscribers. For this example it could be like this :

```
public class MyEventArgs{
    public String Prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

Next fire it as-is in your class :

```
SomethingChanged?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs() { Prop1="test" });
```

Finnally handle it like this :

```
private void OnSomethingChanged(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO
}
```

**NB** You need to subscribe to the event in order to enter in the `OnSometingChanged` method. Subscribe like this :

```
myClass.SomethingChanged+=OnSomethingChanged;
```

Where `myClass` is an instance of the class where you define `SomethingChanged`

Comment: I don't see how `SomethingChanged` ever becomes not null, and Visual Studio is saying "'SomethingChanged' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor."