# How to create a textchange event for usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that contains a textbox and some buttons.

I can't respond to the text changed event from the textbox from outside of that user control (say from the parent form that the control is placed on).

How can I get an event that raised when the text has changed from outside of the user control?

Comment: Are you able to post some of your code?

Comment: create and subscribe to events to pass info to outside of user control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500559/create-custom-wpf-event) on how to create a custom event in WPF.

Following this approach, you can handle the "TextChanged" event for the textbox inside your user control, then raise a custom event from there.

Comment: thank you. your answer and this post help me to right solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486377/how-to-add-an-event-to-a-usercontrol-in-c

Answer (score 0):

in your textcontrol event change, put this:

```
 Me.OnTextChanged(e)
```

Or create your own event

Upper code:

```
 Public Event ClaveModificada(Causa As String)
```

and when you need:

```
RaiseEvent ClaveModificada("")
```